# How to check if a character is from a specific charset in Java?

Tags: java, string, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a method that converts a line from a file from a given charset( utf-8 or latin1) to another one. When translating from utf-8 to latin1, I am supposed to show only the characters that could've not been converted( as this is what happens when trying from utf-8 to latin1). 
I am interesested to check how a single character has or has not been traslated.

```
 private String transcodeLineFromTo(String string, Charset fromCharset, Charset toCharset) {
        try {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes(fromCharset));
            CharBuffer data = fromCharset.decode(inputBuffer);
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = toCharset.encode(data);

            byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();
            String originalLine  = new String(outputData);
            String convertedLine = new String(outputData, toCharset);
            StringBuilder notEncoded = new StringBuilder();
            char[] lineCharacters = convertedLine.toCharArray();
            for (char ch : lineCharacters) {
                if () {
                    notEncoded.append();
                }
            }
            if (!notEncoded.toString().equals("")) {
                return notEncoded.toString();
            } else {
                return convertedLine;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense. Since the method receives a `String`, the `fromCharset` has already been applied when reading lines from the file using a `BufferedReader`, so the method should not use that for anything. Remove parameter from method and re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check is encoded by possible by calling Charset `canEncode` function. Try with this:

```
private String transcodeLineFromTo(String string, Charset fromCharset, Charset toCharset) {
        try {
            StringBuilder notEncoded = new StringBuilder();
            char[] lineCharacters = string.toCharArray();
            for (char ch : lineCharacters) {
                if (!toCharset.newEncoder().canEncode(ch)) {
                    notEncoded.append(ch);
                }
            }
            if (!notEncoded.toString().equals("")) {
                return notEncoded.toString();
            } else {
                return new String(toCharset.newEncoder().encode(fromCharset.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes(fromCharset)))).array(),toCharset);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I tried to use `toCharset.newEncoder().canEncode(ch)` at some point, yet I was not sure about its usage. Also thanks for rethinking the method's logic!

Comment: Can you explain what the line `new String(toCharset.newEncoder().encode(fromCharset .decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes(fromCharset)))).array(),toCharset)` is supposed to do?

Comment: its encode your string from fromCharset to toCharset

Comment: @Holger sry.... did not notice... btw frist take byte buffer from string of fromCharset...then  decode it with fromCharSet... next encode with toCharSet...finally take string from charbuffer....i just converted op first 6 line code to one line cause op return it if encode possible

Comment: …ending up at the same string as before. encodeᶠʳᵒᵐ→decodeᶠʳᵒᵐ→encodeᵗᵒ→decodeᵗᵒ. It’s also questionable why the function returns the characters it couldn’t encode when there are some, but the original string (after performing redundant conversions) when there are none. The caller can’t tell these contradicting results apart. I understand that this logic is already in the question, but since the answer is supposed to solve the asker’s problems, it’s worth pointing out the issue instead of taking over the logic.